# Unable to transfer file with <scp> Ant task and username containing spaces

Tags: ant

I am using the following Ant script with username and IP address. I want to transfer a file. If username has a space in it, the file is not transferring.

```
<project name="Hello World Project" default="info">
  <property file="build.properties"/>
  <target name="info">
    <scp file="/home/smith/Gjs/ws2/abc.txt"
      todir="Srupanan k:rakesh@19.1.21.6:~/" trust="true"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Is there any way to use `<scp>` with a username containing a space?

Comment: Can you try the following? Encasing the username within single-quotes, escaping the space with a backslash, two backslashes?

Comment: Is it like this -'Srupanan\\k'.

Comment: no, like this : 'Srupanan\ k' ; space, the special character, is escaped by prefixing it with a \ in order for it to lose its special meaning

Comment: now i am getting exception as com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out.
Is there anything to be added to my code?

Comment: I don't know, it looks good to me, but I haven't used ant in a while. Have you made sure you had connectivity to 19.1.21.6 from the computer running ant? If it is easy to you, could you maybe check the network packets to see if ant is actually reaching for the good host?

Comment: ya i have pinged.my system has well connection with it.I am able to transfer file to some systems and not for other some even though systems are well connected.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code and from what I saw, the ant task does not mind spaces at all, it only checks for the : and @ in the toDir.

There might be a problem in the Jsch library it uses to handle the ssh connection, although I doubt it would be easy to debug and fix. You should however make sure you're using an up-to-date installation of ant.

You could also try to use the sftp flag of the ant task in hope that the sftp implementation will handle spaces better.

If all fails you should still be able use an exec task to upload via a native scp call.

Good luck !